# Find a function which takes f(x) as parameter and return the value of the derivative

Tags: calculus, neural-networks

I am trying to program my own activation function for a neural network.

I am trying to do the same thing as for the Bipolar sigmoid function in [this example](http://code.google.com/p/aforge/source/browse/trunk/Sources/Neuro/Activation+Functions/BipolarSigmoidFunction.cs?r=1698) but for the hyperbolic tangent.

This is how its done for the bipolar sigmoid function:
$$
f(x) =  {2 \over (1 + e^{-\alpha x}  ) - 1}
$$

$$
f'(x) =  {\alpha  (1 - f(x) f(x) )\over  2 }
$$

With $y = f(x)$
$$
f'(y) =  {\alpha  (1 - y y )\over  2 }
$$

For the hyperbolic tangent
$$
f(x) =  tanh(x)
$$

$$
f'(x) =  sech^2(x) 
$$

$$
f'(y) =   ??
$$

How can I find f '(y) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean what I think you mean (turning a derivative into a differential equation basically):

$$f'(x)=sech^2 x = 1 - tanh^2 x = 1- f(x)^2 $$